# GDI+: Alternatives to DrawReversible for visual selection indicators?

Tags: c#, gdi+, drawing, bitmap

I've searched around for **an alternative way of drawing selection indicators for visual objects** (like selected edges, lines etc.) **without the use of `ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame`** and related XOR methods. The reasons are unwanted XOR-ing "artifacts", reversibility not applying to bitmaps, no control of the actual visual look and slowness.

On the other hand I want to **avoid having to repaint the whole scene** (map actually) if a user decides he wants to deselect an object or two, because the repaint could be quite expensive.

So the only alternative I can see is implementing some basic drawing logic directly on a `Bitmap`, but with **storing the previous contents of the pixels** before they change. Then (in theory) I would be able to reapply old contents of, say, an selected edge rectangle if the user chooses to deselect that edge.

My question is whether you think this is a good idea or do you see some other alternatives to my problem (within the GDI+)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the selection indicator is just drawn on the top of the unselected object, you can use two bitmaps, draw all the unselected objects on the background one and the selection indicators on the other, and paint them both on screen.
Else, you can do the same, except that you render the selected objects instead of just indicators.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I'll try it sometime

Answer (score 0):

Only store the rectangles "of interest" in an off screen buffer. And repaint when the focus is lost. . . Or if you can redraw just the portion as it appears normally based on in memory data you should be fine.  Otherwise it seems that you have the gist of it.